# How to not block ui running plugin in intellij idea

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for intellij. when user clicks on the action, the process will take so long, and there's no way I can reduce time it takes to process and while the process is running, whole intellij is freeze, so I thought maybe starting new thread and do the process inside that thread will stop intellij to freeze but I get the following error:

```
Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6,4,main] 1624577559
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] 40587587 
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.RuntimeExceptionWithAttachments: EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false
Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6,4,main] 1624577559
SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] 40587587
```

The Action class is:

```
public class MQLAction extends AnAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(@NotNull AnActionEvent event) {
        ModuleProjectUtil.getInstance().setEvent(event);
        ModuleProjectUtil.getInstance().setProject(event.getProject());
        Runnable runnable = new RunMqlThread();
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().executeOnPooledThread(runnable);
    }
}
```

and RunMqlThread is:

```
public class RunMqlThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (ActionsUtil.noEditorFound(ModuleProjectUtil.getInstance().getEvent())) {
            return;
        }

        String fileExtension = ActionsUtil.getFileExtension(ModuleProjectUtil.getInstance().getEvent());

        // Check if file is java then insert it if its mql then run it
        boolean isFileJava = fileExtension.equals(JAVA_EXTENSION);
        boolean isFileMQL = fileExtension.equals(MQL_EXTENSION);
        ProjectsMainService mainService = new ProjectsMainServiceImpl();
        if (isFileJava) {
            mainService.importJPO();
        } else if (isFileMQL) {
            mainService.runMQL();
        }
    }
}
```

What does the error say, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The SDK documentation contains a section about threading: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/general-threading-rules.html

Comment: You seem to have left off the error part of the error message. You're probably trying to modify data that intellij checks to make sure you're on the EDT when you modify it.